# AWK Equivalent Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

In a UNIX script I've been successful in doing the following and would like to know how the equivalent would be done using Javascript:

In row 4 and in field 5 of the input file I can extract a Purchase Order number:

```
PO=$(awk 'FNR == 4 {print $5}' $FileName)
```

In row 12 and in field 2 I can extract a vendor number in that same file:

```
vendor=$(awk 'FNR == 12 {print $2}' $FileName)
```

What would these statements in JavaScript look like, please?

Comment: please show some sample input. you probably don't need a full `awk` re-implementation in JS to extract whatever it is you're looking for. that said you [can](http://awk.js.org/) get it running in the browser if you really want to.

Comment: How do you represent your data in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you read the file into a string

```
filecontent = readfile()
filecontent.split("\n")[4 - 1].split(" ")[5 - 1]
filecontent.split("\n")[12 - 1].split(" ")[2 - 1]
```

Explanation

- `.split("\n")` separates the file into individual lines (so for matching of FNR)
- `[4 - 1]` takes line 4 (FNR == 4) (0-indexed)
- `.split(" ")` tokenizes the line
- `[2 - 1]` as before, entry 2